# build.gradle file not compile

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors, build.gradle, adb

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Felipe\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle' line: 23

Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Felipe\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\Felipe\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle': 23: Unexpected input: '1 >> /system/' @ line 23, column 44.
     ervice.developermode.enable = 1 >> /syst
                                   ^
    echo:
    persist.service.developermode.enable = 1 >> /system/ build.protectionDomain
    echo:
    persist.service.service.adb.enable = 1 >> /system/ build.protectionDomain
    echo:
    persit.debuggable =1 >> /system/ build.protectionDomain
    reboot
    dependencies {compile group(org.bukkit), name: 'bukkit', version: '1.7.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'}
    compile('io.ibj:MattLib:1.1-SNAPSHOT') {exlude group: 'de.bananaco' exclude 'net.milkbow:vault:1.2.27'}
    compile group: 'net.citizensnpcs', name: 'citizens', version: '2.0.12'
    compile group: 'com.sk89q', name: 'worldedit', version: '5.6.1'
    compile group: 'net.milkbowl', name: 'vault', version: '1.2.12'
    compile fileTree(annotationProcessOptions)
    includeCompileClasspath true

}
```

i'm trying to activate USB debugging on my phone with the broken screen... i followed a guide, but i got this error... i'm using Android Studio.

Comment: I think you misunderstood gradle. Gradle is a build system for [app] development that is executed on the device you develop (usually a PC or Mac). It is not a shell script that is executed on the phone. For installing apps you need to have adb enabled, and you can not use gradle to enable it.

Comment: oh okay,what can i do to activate it? since i don't have access to the device because the screen is broken...

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen